# Beyasian changepoint detection notation

Tags: notation, bayesian

I'm reading [this article](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ejs/1539050490) and I'm having some problems in understanting basics or notation.

Article is about detecting changepoint with bayesian approach. So we have vector with data $Y = \{y_1, y_2,\ldots, y_n\}$ and if there are $k$ changes in moments $t_1,\ldots, t_k$ we split $Y$ into $(y_1,\ldots,y_{t_1-1}), (y_{t_1},\ldots,y_{t_2-1}),\ldots, (y_{t_k},...y_n)$. And after that my problem begins. In the article we read

> In a Bayesian formulation the joint
> posterior distribution for the latent changepoint indicator vector $z$ and segment
> parameters $θ = \{θ_1,\ldots,θ_{k+1}\}$ can be written as a product of the full segment
> likelihood $(2.2)$ and the priors for $z$ and $θ$, (...)

where $\theta$ is a parametr from likelihood estimation.

I'm not a native english speaker so I don't really understand that sentence and so on the next equation

[equation from article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V11ho.png)

that $\pi$ function came from nothing (for me) and what does "$\alpha$" mean?

Greetings

Comment: It seems that $\pi$ is "the joint posterior distribution for the latent changepoint indicator vector z and segment parameters θ" and $\propto$ means "is proportional to".

Comment: If you want me to explain something further, please tell me.

Comment: Thank you for ur answers. Still i don't really understand how can I find $\pi$ - the equation mentioned in post means $ \pi ( z, \theta | y) = (\prod (...)) $ right?

$f(y_i |\theta_j) $ means density of $y$ until parametr $\theta_j$ fits to $y$ (so until the change occurs) so it should be known (if i have got $y$, and $\theta$ is its mean or variance. But further we have $\pi (\theta_j)$ and $\pi (z)$.
How can i get those joint posterior distribution in Bayes approach?